# remove dependency on CRT in dll

Tags: windows, dll, crt

I'm building a dll on Visual Studio 2010, and I'm using some simple C functions like `fprintf` and `fread`, and it's linking to `msvcr100.dll` by default.

This dll is going to be loaded into an app that may be using a different CRT version (eg. `msvcr90.dll`, `msvcrt.dll`).

Since I know the app's going to load a CRT before my dll gets loaded, can I remove the dependency on `msvcr100.dll` and use the C functions in the CRT loaded by the app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When building a DLL; what type of CRT should I link to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262519/when-building-a-dll-what-type-of-crt-should-i-link-to)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided to build the DLL against the lowest common denominator CRT version used by the target app, `msvcr90.dll`.

I did this by using the MSVC toolchain, available with Visual C++ 2008 Express (free).

I did try the mingw/gcc toolchain, which allows you to specify which CRT version to link against (see [mingw-rt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/mingw-rt/) and [gcc -specs=msvcr**](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/SpecsFileHOWTO)), however, `msvcr90.dll` is a new-style SxS assembly so I couldn't get the produced executable to run properly.

It may be worth considering skipping linking against `msvcr**.dll` entirely; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146469/can-i-use-msvcrt-functions-in-my-dll-delay-load-handler-function) and `VC/include/delayhlp.cpp`.